# Excel Lookup for work sheet comparison

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007, lookup

I have 3 sheets. The first one contains data for Shop A, the second data for Shop B, and the last sheet contains the results.

Sheet A & B: Item Code, Name, Brand,and Stock

[image: Data sheet of Shops A & B]

I want to compare the stock of Shop A and Shop B, like this:

[image: Desired Result]

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a `VLOOKUP()`. In cell E2 of your results worksheet, enter

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,$A$13:$D$20,4,0)
```

This finds your item code (**A1**) in your shop B data (**$A$13:$D$20** in your image above) and pulls out the stock in the **4**th column of that table. You want exact matches only so enter **0** at the end to specify that.

If for any reason Shop B doesn't have an item appearing in your list for Shop A, this formula will return an error. To get round this you can expand your formula like this, so it returns 0 instead of #N/A:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,$A$13:$D$20,4,0),0)
```